# ANTLR4 Arith Expression visitor order operation

Tags: python, antlr4, visitor-pattern

I am trying to understand how visitor context work in python version of **ANTLR4**

I am using the Python3 grammar and I trying to visit "arith_expr"

with this input example **x = 10 + 50 - 50** I have this context in the visitor

`len(ctx.term()) = 3` is the value of `atom [10,50,50]`

```
len(ctx.ADD()) = 1

len(ctx.MINUS()) = 1
```

What is the order of the operator?

```
arith_expr  
    : term (('+'|'-') term)*    
    ;

class Arith_exprContext(ParserRuleContext):

        def __init__(self, parser, parent:ParserRuleContext=None, invokingState:int=-1):
            super().__init__(parent, invokingState)
            self.parser = parser

        def term(self, i:int=None):
            if i is None:
                return self.getTypedRuleContexts(MBIParser.TermContext)
            else:
                return self.getTypedRuleContext(MBIParser.TermContext,i)


        def ADD(self, i:int=None):
            if i is None:
                return self.getTokens(MBIParser.ADD)
            else:
                return self.getToken(MBIParser.ADD, i)

        def MINUS(self, i:int=None):
            if i is None:
                return self.getTokens(MBIParser.MINUS)
            else:
                return self.getToken(MBIParser.MINUS, i)

        def getRuleIndex(self):
            return MBIParser.RULE_arith_expr

        def enterRule(self, listener:ParseTreeListener):
            if hasattr( listener, "enterArith_expr" ):
                listener.enterArith_expr(self)

        def exitRule(self, listener:ParseTreeListener):
            if hasattr( listener, "exitArith_expr" ):
                listener.exitArith_expr(self)

        def accept(self, visitor:ParseTreeVisitor):
            if hasattr( visitor, "visitArith_expr" ):
                return visitor.visitArith_expr(self)
            else:
                return visitor.visitChildren(self)
```

this is the override visitor def

```
def visitArith_expr(self, ctx:MBIParser.Arith_exprContext):
    
    print(len(ctx.term())) #3
    self.visit(ctx.term(0)) #10
    self.visit(ctx.term(1)) #50
    self.visit(ctx.term(2)) #50

    print(len(ctx.ADD())) #1
    print(len(ctx.MINUS())) #1
    
    return self.visitChildren(ctx)
```

Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

You could collect all operators inside a list like this:

```
arith_expr
  : term (operators+=('+'|'-') term)*
  ;
```

The `operators` is a list and contains all operators. You can then do something like this in your visitor:

```py
def visitArith_expr(self, ctx):
    result = self.visit(ctx.term(0))

    for i in range(len(ctx.operators)):
        if ctx.operators[i].type == MBILexer.ADD:
            result += self.visit(ctx.term(i + 1))
        else:
            result -= self.visit(ctx.term(i + 1))

    return result

def visitTerm(self, ctx):
    return int(ctx.getText())
```

Or better, do something like this:

```
expr
  : expr ('+' | '-') expr #add_expr
  | term                  #term_expr
  ;
```

in which case the visitor will get a lot easier:

```py
# expr ('+' | '-') expr #add_expr
def visitAdd_expr(self, ctx):
    if ctx.ADD() is not None:
        return self.visit(ctx.expr(0)) + self.visit(ctx.expr(1))
    return self.visit(ctx.expr(0)) - self.visit(ctx.expr(1))

# term                  #term_expr
def visitTerm_expr(self, ctx):
    return self.visit(ctx.term())

def visitTerm(self, ctx):
    return int(ctx.getText())
```